# Return response error 500 React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I am using `react-native` framework for developing my small android app.I'm trying to redirect to Home.js from index.android.js.when i run it,it showing red error message on my Emulator

**index.android.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {AppRegistry,Text,View} from 'react-native';
import Home from 'App/Component/Home';

export default class mylApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
         <Home />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('reactTutorialApp', () => reactTutorialApp);
```

**Home.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Text,View} from 'react-native';


class Home extends Component {
   state = {
      myTxt: 'hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii';
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <View>
            <Text>
               {this.state.myTxt}
            </Text>
         </View>
      );
   }
}

export default Home;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with this import Path `import Home from 'App/Component/Home';`. I assume the Home.js is inside the Project(Folder) -> App (Folder) -> Component (Folder) -> Home.js. If it so then you need import like this `import Home from './App/Component/Home';`

**Update 1:**

**index.android.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {AppRegistry,Text,View} from 'react-native';
import Home from './App/Component/Home';

export default class mylApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
         <Home />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('reactTutorialApp', () => mylApp);
```

**Update 2**

**Home.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Text,View} from 'react-native';


class Home extends Component {
   state = {
      myTxt: 'hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii'
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <View>
            <Text>
               {this.state.myTxt}
            </Text>
         </View>
      );
   }
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: now it showing `Unexpected token, expected , (6:24)
  at C:\Users\Yasiru\AndroidStudioProjects\New folder\reactTutorialApp\App\Components\Home.js`

Comment: yes i have replaced both index and home js with your code.but it's showing unexpected token in home.js file

Comment: In state `myTxt: 'hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii';` you have to remove semicolon